# After reinstalling R and RStudio, RStudio crashes when opening

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

RStudio crashes when opening and produces the failure report below. Did not understand what to do really. How do I solve it?

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium " (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/rsession
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*/Users/Oz/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-Oz.log*

```
27 Jan 2023 00:51:29 [rsession-Oz] ERROR Handle httpd request error: Error : mutate.Rd:134: object 'methods_rd' not found
; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::help::(anonymous namespace)::handleHttpdRequest(const std::string &, const rstudio::session::modules::help::(anonymous namespace)::HandlerSource &, const http::Request &, const Filter &, http::Response *) [Filter = rstudio::session::modules::help::(anonymous namespace)::HelpContentsFilter] src/cpp/session/modules/SessionHelp.cpp:855
01 Feb 2023 00:22:34 [rsession-Oz] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path: /Users/Oz/.local/share/rstudio/notebooks/C80BEAAD-bias-in-turnout/1/63BE219BEDFCCF2/chunks.json, target-path: /Users/Oz/.local/share/rstudio/notebooks/C80BEAAD-bias-in-turnout/1/s/chunks.json]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::copy(const rstudio::core::FilePath &, bool) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:779; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::(anonymous namespace)::onDocPendingRemove(boost::shared_ptr<source_database::SourceDocument>) src/cpp/session/modules/rmarkdown/NotebookCache.cpp:249
```

I was having some problems with my existing RStudio. I deleted and reinstalled it. It did not work and produced the report I post here.